# Move SDL window in SDL 1.2

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, sdl, sdl-1.2

I am using SDL 1.2 with FFmpeg on MAC. I am trying to build a video player using both FFmpeg and SDL. I am viewing my video on SDL_Surface. My player is working fine. Now my problem is, i want to move SDL window without dragging it from title bar. Is there any function/method in SDL 1.2 framework for moving SDL_Surface.

Comment: *i want to move SDL window*... with keyboard? Programatically? randomly?

Comment: programatically..do u have any idea..??

Comment: when my sdl window pops up i want to make it centralized according to my desktop screen. do u have any idea..??

Comment: Show us your code :)

Comment: i am doing this: `SDL_BlitSurface(Bmpsrc,NULL,screen,&rect); SDL_Flip(screen);`  where Bmpsrc and screen are SDL_Surfaces

Answer (score 3):

SDL 1.2 does not have an API for moving windows. SDL 2.0 has better support for multiple windows and window management in general.
See http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowPosition

To do this with SDL 1.2, you'll need to use platform-specific calls using the window handle.  You can get that with `SDL_GetWMInfo()`.

If you just need to set the initial position of the window so it is centered, then try this before `SDL_SetVideoMode()`:

```
SDL_putenv("SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS=center");
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is:

```
void SDL_SetWindowPosition(SDL_Window* window,
                           int         x,
                           int         y)
```

Which set the position of the window for you.

Comment: this function is defined in SDL 2.0 but i am using SDL 1.2. Is there any other way for SDL 1.2 ?

Comment: @DevSam do you've got something like `SetWindowPos` to use it like so : `SetWindowPos(pInfo.window, 0, r.left, r.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);`